# Once clicked and menu open, click go to page - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a dropdown with jQuery.

So far I have written my code to show the menu, but once open and my users clicks an item, the menu then closes.

Anybody have an idea of how to combat this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8fnhb6yr/

// Language selector

```
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e){

if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65 );
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check also if `e.target` parent is `li.sub-lang` like the following

```js
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e){
 if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('sub-lang')) {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).css('height', 'auto');
 } else {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65 );
 }
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
li ul {display:none;}
li.sub-lang.active ul {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sub-lang">
                <a href="">English</a>
                <ul style="">
                    
                    <li><a href="/en/">International</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="">UK &amp; Ireland</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu close because you listen to the `click` event on the menu (`.sub-lang`).

When you click on a children, the event will "bubble" and the parent will have the event too. So you have to listen to the `click` event on children too to prevent it to bubble :

```
$('.sub-lang ul a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[I edited your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fnhb6yr/2/)